# Installing packages under R devel version

Tags: r

I'm using the current R-devel version (3.3.0, r68650). If I try to install an R package then the following error occurs:

```
> install.packages('RCurl')
 --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
 Error in url("https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv") :
   https:// URLs are not supported
```

Actually I read that to be able to use https urls I have to install RCurl first.

As next I tried to set the repos parameter explicit to the HTTP version:

```
> install.packages('RCurl', repos='http://cran.r-project.CRAN_mirrors.csv')
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.r-project.CRAN_mirrors.csv/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘RCurl’ is not available (for R Under development)
```

The problem appears is not only with the RCurl package but any package I tried.

how can I install packages on the R Development version?

Comment: May I ask why do you use the devel version of R?

Comment: I have to check some package (R CMD check) with the develop version to see if there are some problems with dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick a mirror from that csv file.  The csv isn't a mirror itself.

Comment: Thank you. :) Didn't know it. I spend couple hours on this before ... 

Somehow the first error still occurs (the HTTPS urls not supported one). But I can just provide the mirror explicitly..